# The fraction of groups with normal Hall subgroups

Tags: gr.group-theory

Dear all,

I am a student on computer science. So please forgive me if I state some results in a weird way, and I hope I ask an interesting question to you.

The question is related to finite groups with normal Hall subgroups. I want to know for groups of size $n$, what is the fraction of groups with normal Hall subgroups compared to all groups, up to isomorphism.

For example, we know that for given s, the number of non-isomorphic groups of size $n$ is bounded by $n^{O((\log n)^2)}$. While I can prove that for certain class of groups with normal Hall subgroup, for a given n, the number of non-isomorphic groups of size n can be $n^{\Omega(\log n)}$. But I would like to know an upper bound.

Thank you very much.

Jimmy

Comment: I wonder if there is a meaningful question here that is not going to to be distorted by the prevalence of $p$-groups. For example they tell me about the 49487365422 groups of order 1024. 

Comment: I don't quite understand your statement, but I think I am asking for an asymptotic estimate. Of course it may be the case that for this question the fraction may not converge. Or I am asking "how many groups with at least one normal Hall subgroup are there for a given order", in the spirit of the classical question "how many groups are there for a given order".

Comment: I think the growth rate for the total number of groups of order (at most) $n$ is more or less the same as just for $2$-groups, so requiring a normal Hall subgroup isn't such a strong restriction.  One could however define a function $f(n)$ to be the number of groups of order at most $n$ with *no* normal Hall subgroups.  Perhaps $f(n)$ grows roughly as fast as the total number of groups, perhaps not.  This may be an interesting question.

Comment: @Jimmy: I'm saying that the upper bound may well be trivial (the same order as the number of isomorphism classes), and for reasons that are also trivial from what we know, namely that 2-groups dominate. 

Comment: Just to clarify : are you asking for at least one normal Hall subgroup, or all Hall subgroups normal (which would say nilpotent, so I doubt this is your question). 

In any case, you may be interested by this paper http://www.math.auckland.ac.nz/~obrien/research/gnu.pdf
and related ones by Eamonn O'Brien and his co-authors here
http://www.math.auckland.ac.nz/~obrien/research

Comment: @cdr: Thank you for the statement that the total number of groups of order (at most) n is roughly the same as 2-groups. Due to my background I am not able to see this. I was trying to find the book Enumeration of Finite Groups but I am not at school now. Do you think in this situation, maybe we can consider the number of groups of the form $p^r\cdot q^s$? Because in this case we can talk about groups with normal Hall subgroups.

Comment: @Charles: from the statement that 2-groups dominate, and 2-groups can not have normal Hall subgroups, shouldn't it follow that the upper bound can not be $n^{O((\log n)^2)}$? 

Comment: @BS: Thank you for the reference. I was trying to say the first case, namely at least one normal Hall subgroup.

Comment: @Jimmy: No it doesn't follow, because it also means there are a huge number of isomorphism classes that are (say) a product of a 2-group with a group of order 3. And those have Hall subgroups. The current question seems to be formulated in a way that doesn't seem to be sufficiently discriminating of cases that would be interesting.

Comment: I like the questions: what fraction of groups of order p^r q^s have a normal Sylow p-subgroup.  I tentatively think it would be "most" if p>q (and r,s are large enough). For n=1536, 98.9% have a normal Sylow 3, 2.5% have a normal Sylow 2, and 0.02% have no normal Sylow.

Comment: @Charles: Thanks. Now I understand. Forgive me for my slow response! 

A small refinement of your statement is as follows: note that it is not necessary that all groups of order $2^k\cdot 3$ have a normal Hall subgroup. But all groups of order $3^k\cdot 2$ have normal Hall subgroups.

Comment: @Jack: Yes, your question is more interesting from what I understand.